# How can I store multiple records in hasMany relation Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two models (Post and Tags) and I need to attach multiple tags with Post. Single tag attach is working fine but I'm having trouble with making it multiple.

Model (Post):

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tag', 'id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Controller (Post):

```
public function store()
{
    ...
    $posts->tag_id = $data['tag_id'];
    ...
}
```

Blade (Post create form):

```
<select name="tag_id">
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

What should I do to save multiple tags as relation?

Comment: how can Posts have multiple Tags if there is a `tag_id` on `posts`?

Answer (score 0):

-> first, you need to make select use multiple options, like this :

```
<select name="tagIDs[]" multiple>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->title }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

and notice I named the select **tagIDs[]** so it sends the selected values as array.

-> second, I assume the relationship between Posts and Tags is a ManyToMany. So you have a pivot table **post_tag** that has column **post_id** and **tag_id**.

in your post controller:

```
public function store()
{
    ...
    if ($post->save()) {
        $post->tags()->sync($request->input('tagIDs', []));
    }
    ...
}
```

what sync does is synchronize the tag IDs you sent in request to the post (can be used in update post too)

Comment: Marwane Ezzaze, thank you, but what if I have hasMany relationship (Post hasMany Tags) without backward relationship (no Tags belongsTo Post)? I actually don't need backward relationship, only that Post can have many tags. Do I still need that pivot table?